# How to use git over custom ssh software?

Tags: linux, git, ssh, openssh

SSH in our country is blocked, So I have to use a forked ssh software called [obfuscated-openssh](http://nihilex.com/obfuscated-openssh) , I installed it in /opt directory in linux OS , How can I force git to use `/opt/ob-openssh/bin/ssh` not `/usr/bin/ssh` ?

Answer (score 5):

Use the `GIT_SSH` environment variable to point to your version of ssh.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to set the environment variable `GIT_SSH` to point at your SSH client.

From the man page:

> **GIT_SSH**
>
> If this environment variable is set then git fetch and git push will use this command instead of ssh when they need to connect to
>   a remote system. The `$GIT_SSH` command will be given exactly two
>   arguments: the username@host (or just host) from the URL and the shell command to execute on that remote system.
>
> To pass options to the program that you want to list in `GIT_SSH` you will need to wrap the program and options into a shell
>   script, then set `GIT_SSH` to refer to the shell script.
>
> Usually it is easier to configure any desired options through your personal .ssh/config file. Please consult your ssh
>   documentation for further details.